# How to merge multiple arrays in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to merge two arrays, but getting `NULL`. Below is my code

```
$a = 1;
foreach($codes as $values) {
$id = $values['id'];
$post_data = array ( 
    "id" => $id,
    "name" => $this->input->post('Name'),
    "from_date" => $this->input->post('FromDate'),
    "to_date" => $this->input->post('ToDate')
    );
    $this->data['output' . $a++] = $this->my_modal->simple_post($post_data);
}

$this->data['output'] = array_merge($this->data['output1'], $this->data['output2']);

var_dump($this->data['output']);
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete the first parameter (`NULL`) of `array_merge();`

And what is `$this->input->$id`? Don't you mean `$id`?

And in this environment, it's better to use `array_push();`:

```
$a = 1;
$this->data['output'] = array();
foreach($codes as $values)
{
    $id = $values['id'];
    $post_data = array ( 
    "id" => $id,
    "name" => $this->input->post('Name'),
    "from_date" => $this->input->post('FromDate'),
    "to_date" => $this->input->post('ToDate')
    );

    $new_data = $this->my_modal->simple_post($post_data);
    array_push($this->data['output'], $new_data);
}

var_dump($this->data['output']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $a = 1;
 $this->data['output'] = array();
 foreach($codes as $values){
$id = $values['id'];
$post_data = array ( 
"id" => $id,
"name" => $this->input->post('Name'),
"from_date" => $this->input->post('FromDate'),
"to_date" => $this->input->post('ToDate')
);

$data['output2']= $this->my_modal->simple_post($post_data);
if(count($this->data['output1']) > 1)   {
        $this->data['all']      =   array_merge($this->data['output1'],$data['output2']);
    }else {
        $this->data['all']      =   $data['output1'];
    }
 }
 print_r($this->data['all']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly right, the only problem is that you start the counter with `$a = 1`, and do `$a++` which will result in 2. So the `output1` does not exist. However if you write (notice the subtle change):

```
$a = 1;
foreach($codes as $values) {
    $id = $values['id'];
    $post_data = array ( 
        "id" => $id,
        "name" => $this->input->post('Name'),
        "from_date" => $this->input->post('FromDate'),
        "to_date" => $this->input->post('ToDate')
    );
    $this->data['output' . $a] = $this->my_modal->simple_post($post_data); // $a = 1 now
    $a++; // $a becomes 2 here
}

$this->data['output'] = array_merge($this->data['output1'], $this->data['output2']);

var_dump($this->data['output']);
```